# MVC Model Navigation Links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to do a simple MVC project.  The idea is to select information from the database and display it on a map.  This is an upgrade/replacement of a previous job not written in MVC.  New features are desired that MVC should make easy (to maintain).

The database is a vendor database, and I can make no changes.  I have added 4 views:

- vwMapsDrivers  Driver Details
- vwMapsVehicles  Vehicle Details
- vwMapsIncidents  Incident Details
- vwMapsLogs Log Entries

The basic plan is to list Incidents, with attached driver and vehicle info, and a collection of Logs from the start of the incident to the end of the incident (+ a threshold either way).

This is the **MainContext** class

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace MapsMVC.Models
{
    public class MainContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VehicleModel> Vehicles { get; set; }

        public DbSet<IncidentModel> Incidents { get; set; }

        public DbSet<DriverModel> Drivers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<LogsModel> Logs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleModel>().ToTable("vwMapsVehicles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IncidentModel>().ToTable("vwMapsIncidents");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DriverModel>().ToTable("vwMapsDrivers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<LogsModel>().ToTable("vwMapsLogs");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the **IncidentModel** class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

namespace CtrackMapsMVC.Models
{
    public class IncidentModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Integer]
        [Min(0)]
        [Display(Name = "Incident Id")]
        public int IncidentId { get; set; }

        [Integer]
        [ForeignKey("Vehicles")]
        [Display(Name = "Vehicle Id")]
        public string NodeId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Incident Start")]
        public DateTime IncidentStart { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Incident End")]
        public DateTime IncidentEnd { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Incident Type")]
        public string IncidentType { get; set; }

        [Integer]
        [Min(0)]
        [ForeignKey("Logs")]
        [Display(Name = "First Log Id")]
        public int FirstLogId { get; set; }

        [Integer]
        [Min(0)]
        [ForeignKey("Logs")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Log Id")]
        public int LastLogId { get; set; }

        [Integer]
        [Min(0)]
        [ForeignKey("Drivers")]
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Driver")]
        [Display(Name = "Driver Node Id")]
        public int DriverNodeId { get; set; }

        public virtual VehicleModel Vehicle { get; set; }
        public virtual DriverModel Driver { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LogsModel> Logs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the **VehicleModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

namespace CtrackMapsMVC.Models
{
    public class VehicleModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Integer]
        [Min(0)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Node Id")]
        public int NodeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Vehicle Name")]
        public string VehicleName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Vehicle Description")]
        public string VehicleDescription { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Cellnumber")]
        public string Cellnumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Received")]
        public DateTime LastReceived { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Unit Type")]
        public string NodeTypeDesc { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Site Code")]
        public string SiteCode { get; set; }

    }


}
```

The **LogsModel** and **DriverModel** are pretty straightforward.

The site compiles with no problem, with the Controllers being default generated boilerplate.  The Views are also generated, but the Edit/Delete pages are removed, as are link references in the Index.

The home page loads.  When trying to load /Vehicle/Index I get the following exception:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'NodeId' on type 'CtrackMapsMVC.Models.IncidentModel' is not valid. The navigation property 'Vehicles' was not found on the dependent type 'CtrackMapsMVC.Models.IncidentModel'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

What am I doing wrong with my Foreign key declaration?  How can I fix it?  Some reading has implied it won't work because the SQL VIews dont actually have FK relationships (not possible to define). Is there an extension that will help?  Sure coding against views isn't that uncommon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you set here: `[ForeignKey("Vehicles")]` is your navigation property which you set to Vehicles but you included `public virtual VehicleModel Vehicle { get; set; }` which is Vehicle and not Vehicles.

Ref:
http://peterkellner.net/2012/04/07/gaining-some-control-back-from-microsofts-entity-framework-code-first-name-your-own-foreign-keys/

Comment: So, because I specify the 3 properties down the bottom             
`public virtual VehicleModel Vehicle { get; set; }`
`public virtual DriverModel Driver { get; set; }`
`public virtual ICollection<LogsModel> Logs { get; set; }`
I don't need the FOreignKey reference?

Comment: Changing the ForeignKey annotation to `[ForeignKey("Vehicle")]` has just led to another exception **{"Unable to determine a composite foreign key ordering for foreign key on type CtrackMapsMVC.Models.IncidentModel. When using the ForeignKey data annotation on composite foreign key properties ensure order is specified by using the Column data annotation or the fluent API."}**  Which is interesting because I don't think I have a composite key defined.  Unless its counting the FirstLogId and LastLogId, which should be two separate links.

Comment: It's likely your logs model.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#relationships

Comment: Thanks for that reference @james-santiago.  Very helpful, especially [InverseProperty]

Answer (score 0):

This is where `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` based mapping is helpful. Gives you some compile time helpfulness:

```
internal class IncidentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IncidentModel>
{
    public IncidentMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.IncidentId);
        ToTable("vwMapsIncidents");

        HasRequired(m => m.Vehicle)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.NodeID);

        //or if you added a 'Incidents' property on 'Vehicle'

        HasRequired(m => m.Vehicle)
            .WithMany(m => m.Incidents)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.NodeID);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<VehicleModel> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IncidentModel> Incidents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DriverModel> Drivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogsModel> Logs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IncidentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VehicleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DriverMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LogsMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Then remove the all the `[ForeignKey]` attributes from your model.

Good Luck...

[Docs for EntityTypeConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)